# How to show that the integral of bivariate normal density function is 1?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

How to show the following?

$$\large \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2-2 \rho x y}{2(1-\rho^2)}} dx\ dy=1$$

Answer (score 3):

Complete the square of the exponent $x^2+y^2-2\rho xy = \left(x-\rho y\right)^2+y^2(1-\rho^2)=:u^2+y^2(1-\rho^2)$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2-2 \rho x y}{2(1-\rho^2)}} dx dy=\\
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}} du \; e^{-\frac{y^2(1-\rho^2)}{2(1-\rho^2)}} dy = \\
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}} dy=1$$

PS. Using the well known formula that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^2}{a}} du=\sqrt{a\pi}$$

Comment: The question is when doing the change of variables $u=x-\rho y$, the lower and upper bound of the integral is not defined, is it? For example, when x and y goes to infinity at the same time, u could be positive infinity, negative infinity or 0, depending on how x and y goes to infinity.

Comment: No! Doing the integration you choose one specific value of $y$ this could be anything, but is fix, and thus $y$ is not infinity. An alternative approach is applying the limes for each infinity symbol. Then you might see, that the contribution to the result is very tiny for very large and very small values of $y$ or $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use polar coordinates. Put $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$ and Jakobian will be $r$.

Comment: But before that, apply a linear transformation to diagonalize the quadratic form $x^2 + y^2 - 2\rho xy$.

Comment: Please see my comment to the first response for the question.